# My ListView won't work ...it says: "Unfortunately your app has stopped"

Tags: android

I want to know why it tells me: "Unfortunately your app has stopped"?

I followed all the steps in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zQCv0Xb3pk&index=84&list=PLonJJ3BVjZW6hYgvtkaWvwAVvOFB7fkLa

my code in main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView list;
    String[] mimititles;
    String[] description;
    int[] images = {R.drawable.m1,R.drawable.m2,R.drawable.m3,R.drawable.m4,R.drawable.m4,
            R.drawable.m5,R.drawable.m6,R.drawable.m7,R.drawable.m8,R.drawable.m9,R.drawable.m10};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


     Resources  res= getResources();
     mimititles= res.getStringArray(R.array.title);
     description = res.getStringArray(R.array.description);

     list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

    ibrahimadapter adapter = new ibrahimadapter(this,mimititles,images,description);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }



}

class ibrahimadapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>

{
    Context context;
    int[] images;
    String [] tiltearray;
    String [] descrip;

    ibrahimadapter(Context c,String[]titles,int[]imgs,String[] desc )
    {
        super(c,R.layout.single_row,R.id.textView1,titles);
        this.context=c;
        this.images=imgs;
        this.tiltearray=titles;
        this.descrip=desc;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflate = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View raw=inflate.inflate(R.layout.single_row,parent,false);

   ImageView myimage= (ImageView) raw.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
   myimage.setImageResource(images[position]);

   TextView mytitle = (TextView) raw.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
     mytitle.setText(tiltearray[position]);

   TextView mydescription = (TextView) raw.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

     mydescription.setText(descrip[position]);

        return raw;
    }
}
```

my code in activity_main.xml layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:android2="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android2:id="@+id/listView"
        android2:layout_width="match_parent"
        android2:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

my code in single_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/m1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your adapter:

your constructor should be: `public ibrahimadapter(....) {.....}`

getView function change to:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflate = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final Holder holder;
    View raw = converView;
    if(raw == null){
       raw=inflate.inflate(R.layout.single_row,parent,false);
       holder = new Holder();
       holder.imgView = (ImageView) raw.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

       holder.myTitle = (TextView) raw.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

       holder.myDes = (TextView) raw.findViewById(R.id.textView2);


       raw.setTag(holder)
    } else {
    holder=(Holder)raw.getTag();
    }
    holder.imgView.setImageResource(images[position]);
    holder.myTitle.setText(tiltearray[position]);
    holder.myDes.setText(descrip[position]);
    return raw;
}

public static class Holder {
    ImageView imgView;
    TextView myTitle;
    TextView myDes;
}
```

Comment: thank you mt brother but also the same problem  the log cat crash at method  public View in code but i still don't now where is the wrong

Comment: This exception occur because your array have size is 10 but you set value for 11th item at index 10. How many items getStringArray(R.array.title); and res.getStringArray(R.array.description); have?

Comment: thank you a lot   it works ^_^..can i  n ow how you no the exact error from log cat?

Comment: You're welcome ^^, it's ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: that means you had access index which is out of array's length.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
Change this 
super(c,R.layout.single_row,R.id.textView1,titles)

To this 
super(c,R.layout.single_row,titles)

Please check that the number of items for each String[] mimititles, String[] description and int[] images are all of the same length. 
E.g if you want to show 5 item in the List, then you must 5 images, 5 mimititles and 5 description. 
So check your string-array files

Comment: i tray as you say but the same problem

Comment: Please check that the number of items for each  String[] mimititles, String[] description and int[] images are all 10. So check your string-array files

Comment: I've Edited my answer, don't forget to mark it as answered.